# Скрыть все элементы выборки кроме первого

Tags: jquery

Собираюсь скрыть все элементы выборки кроме первого. есть следующая дом структура:

```
<div id="_result">
  <div><!--оставить в живых этот блок-->
    <div>
       <div>...</div>
    </div>
 </div><!-- оставить в живых этот блок-->
 <p>..</p>
 <ul>....</ul>
 <p>..</p>
 <ul>..</ul>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

пишу следующее

```
$("#_result:not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

но не работает,как поправить?

Comment: добавить пробел `$("#_result :not(:eq(0))").hide();`

Comment: @Grundy , не так всё дропается    https://jsfiddle.net/c8qeufuh/1/

Comment: на самом деле не все :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном виде `"#_result:not(:eq(0))"` выражение найдет все элементы с id=_result, которые не являются первыми в выборке, так как такой элемент только один, то он под выборку не попадает.

Для решения нужно искать не первый элемент среди детей, для этого нужно добавить знак `>`

`"#_result>:not(:eq(0))"`

Например:

```js
$("#_result>:not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_result">
  <div>
    <!--оставить в живых этот блок-->
    <div>
      <div>я должен быть виден</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- оставить в живых этот блок-->
  <p>а я нет</p>
  <ul>и я нет</ul>
  <p>и я</p>
  <ul>и я</ul>
  <div>и даже я</div>
</div>
```

Так же можно пойти другим путем и выбирать что нужно оставить в коде

```
$("#_result").children().slice(1).hide();
```

Пример

```js
$("#_result").children().slice(1).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_result">
  <div>
    <!--оставить в живых этот блок-->
    <div>
      <div>я должен быть виден</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- оставить в живых этот блок-->
  <p>а я нет</p>
  <ul>и я нет</ul>
  <p>и я</p>
  <ul>и я</ul>
  <div>и даже я</div>
</div>
```

Comment: вдруг комуто нужно будет если нужно оставить первый и последний элемент то вот  
   
      $("#_result>:not(:eq(0)):not(:last)").hide();

Comment: @vasily_dumov, примеры кода в комментариях лучше не давать, обычно слишком нечитаемо получается, ну и если селектор усложняется, то проще выбирать через код, а не пытаться найти такой селектор, который подходит